# How to Overwrite WP core function get_comments_number comepletely

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, hook

Due to some requirement I need to completely change the behavior of the `get_comments_number();`
A wp core function that returns the number of comments !

What I want is to change its behavior and instead of reading the comment I want it to override with the following function;

```
function get_review_numbers( $post_id = 0 ) {
$post = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        $count = 0;
    } else {
        $count = get_rev_count($post->ID);
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    /**
     * Filter the returned comment count for a post.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @param int $count   Number of comments a post has.
     * @param int $post_id Post ID.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'get_review_numbers', $count, $post_id );
}
```

Please guide me I want when ever I write some where `get_comments_number` it should execute the above function instead of executing its core function.

Answer (score 0):

you can't overwrite functions in php. (theme devs test if function exists then create function to allow new functions to be created if run before that point)

However there is a filter in `get_comments_number`

`return apply_filters( 'get_comments_number', $count, $post_id );`

so you can filter the result with:

```
add_filter('get_comments_number', 'your_custom_funct');

function your_custom_funct($count){
     $count++; // example you can add one to the count, etc
     return $count; //return it when finished!
}
```